# Code Unreachable Error in Code As Warnng

Tags: xna

```
if(Screens.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = Screens.Count -1; i < 0; i +=1)
    {
        if (Screens[i].GrabFocus)
            Screens[i].GrabFocus = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Unreachable Code

Trying to convert
VB  code to C#

```
For I = FoundScreens - 1 to 0 step -1
    if (Screens[i].GrabFocus)
        Screens[i].GrabFocus = true;
    break;
```

Where is my mistake in C#?

Comment: What code is marked as "unreachable"?

Comment: for (int i = Screens.Count -1; i < 0;----> i +=1 <---)

Comment: Then it sounds like `Screens.Count` will never be greater than 0.  (Though it's odd that the compiler would be smart enough to know that.)  Which means the problem has nothing to do with the code posted, but instead with the code which creates the values being examined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance the VB code starts with the last screen in the list to the first one

VB.NET

```
For I = FoundScreens - 1 to 0 step -1
```

To perform the same thing in C#

```
for (int i = Screens.Count -1; i > 0; i--)
```

Your original code, was unreachable, because of the loop condition in the for, which you implemented as such:

```
for (int i = Screens.Count -1; i < 0; i +=1)
```

i< 0, when i is assigned the number of screens it can be 0 to n, so i will never be smaller than 0.

I'm surprised that you would get such a warning in the for because a simple test of this code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 0; i +=1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    } 
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Will show no warnings in a simple console application.